# Line Break in Equation Using empheq

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align, alignat, empheq

I have an equation that overspills into the margins; I am using (and would like to continue using) `empheq` for it.
Let me give a MWE. Note that it's not what I've actually got in my document, just an example of some text spilling into the margin.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{empheq}[ left = {%
    P( X = x, \, Y = y \mid \tau > t, A )
\le
    \empheqlbrace}]
{alignat=2}
    &P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c ) && \quad\text{when}\quad x > 0, \, y \le 0
\\
    &P( Z \neq z \mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A) && \quad\text{when}\quad x \le 0, \, y = 0
\end{empheq}


\[ \hspace{-15em}
    P( X = x, \, Y = y \mid \tau > t, A )
\]
\begin{empheq}[ left = {%
    \le
    \empheqlbrace}]
{alignat=2}
&P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c ) && \quad\text{when}\quad x > 0, \, y \le 0
\\
&P( Z \neq z \mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A) && \quad\text{when}\quad x \le 0, \, y = 0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

If you run this, you'll see two sets of equations. The first one spills into the margins. The second has a line break immediately before the `\le` sign; however, this is simply using `\[ hspace{-15em} ... \]`, which gets the spacing wrong. I'd like to be able to add a linebreak to the `empheq` code, but I cannot work out how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? The left part of  empheq is made up of an `aligned` environment, combined with a `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools`. B.t.w., needless to load `amsmath`nor `mathtools` when you load `empheq`, nor `amsfonts` when you load `amssymb`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{empheq}[left={%
\begin{aligned}[b]P( X={}&\mathrlap{x, \,Y=y\mid\tau > t, A )}\\[2ex]
     & \le
    \end{aligned}
    \empheqlbrace}]%
{alignat=2}
&P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c ) & \quad &\text{when } x > 0, \, y \le 0
\\
&P( Z \neq z \mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A) & & \text{when } x\le 0, \, y = 0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit* : You also have this variant, suggested by egreg, which saves manual adjustments for the alignment point of the `aligned` environment:

```
\begin{empheq}[ left = {%
\begin{aligned}[b]&\mathrlap{P( X={}x, \,Y=y \mid \tau > t, A )}\\[2ex]
     & \quad\le
    \end{aligned}
    \empheqlbrace}]
{alignat=2}
&P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c ) &\quad&\text{when $ x > 0 $, $ y \le 0 $}
\\
&P( Z \neq z\mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A) & & \text{when $ x \le 0 $, $ y = 0 $}
\end{empheq}
```

[image]

A variant that avoids guessing the right amount of vertical spacing in the inner `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{empheq}[left={
  \begin{aligned}[b]
  &\mathrlap{P( X=x, \,Y=y\mid\tau > t, A )}\\
  &\qquad\le\empheqlbrace\end{aligned}
}]{alignat=2}
&P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c ) & \quad &\text{when } x > 0, \, y \le 0
\\
&P( Z \neq z \mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A) & & \text{when } x\le 0, \, y = 0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could do `\begin{aligned}[b]&\mathrlap{<top line>}\\&\quad\le\empheqlbrace\end{aligned}` so not to need manual adjustments for the spacing. I'd also type the conditions as `\text{when $x>0$, $y\le 0$}` to get more uniform appearance.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. And I have used @egreg's edition to make the spacing easier -- especially useful as my real top line has macros in it that make adding `&`s midway through difficult. Thanks to the both of you! :)

Comment: @SamT I'd go with something similar to koleygr's suggestion, though.

Comment: @egreg: I've added you way to the answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Bernard You missed putting `\empheqlbrace` *before* `\end{aligned}`, which makes unnecessary to use ``\\[2ex]`` (and guessing the right spacing).

Comment: @egreg: I tried  it, but I obtained a `Missing { inserted` error message, so I thought the  \empheqlbrace inserted in that position  was a typo in your comment, and I put it where you see it now. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Putting `\empheqlbrace` before `\end{aligned}` worked for me. I did add `\:` after it, as otherwise the brace was *very close* to the next text (ie the two lines, (1) and (2) in your example)

Comment: @Bernard I added it.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext


\begin{empheq}[ left = {%
P( X = x, \, Y = y \mid \tau > t, A )
    \le
    \empheqlbrace}]
{alignat=2}
P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c )\nonumber \\ \hfill\text{when}\quad x > 0, \, y \le 0
\\
P( Z \neq z \mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A)\nonumber\\\hfill\quad\text{when}\quad x \le 0, \, y = 0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**

For the spacing I would adjust it manually like:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext


\begin{empheq}[ left = {%
P( X = x, \, Y = y \mid \tau > t, A )
    \le
    \empheqlbrace}]
{alignat=2}
P( Z = z \mid \zeta > t/2, A^c ) P( A^c )\nonumber \\ \hfill\text{when}\quad x > 0, \, y \le 0
\\
P( Z \neq z \mid \zeta > t^2, A ) P(A) \hspace*{14pt}\nonumber\\\hfill\quad\text{when}\quad x \le 0, \, y = 0
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is quite nice -- +1. But it doesn't answer the question (but gives a viable alternative), so I haven't accepted this answer; I'm still interested in how to do what I originally suggested. But thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Welcome @SamT (you don't have to accept an answer that doesn't really solves your original problem), but I think you have to edit your post to make it more clear since the phrase "I'd like to be able to add a linebreak to the empheq code, but I cannot work out how to do this" is leading to answers like mine... (May be its my English -not really good and didn't understood every word- but I think you could be more clear while waiting for new answers)

Comment: Regardless of whether it's your English or my writing, I know that lots of people on here don't speak English as a first language, so I should write the questions in a way that is easily understandable for them -- so thank you for your feedback :)